# Apache Rewrite condition - any ideas?

Tags: mod-rewrite

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

</VirtualHost>
```

This changes the entire request uri into lowercase. I want this to happen for specific folder(`/css`), but RewriteMap doesn't work in .htaccess. I am a novice in regex and Rewrite. I need a RewriteCond which checks only `/css/<any subfolder> and/or <files>.` can any body help?

EDIT:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

This seems to be working fine for a particular folder - `/css/`. Not sure if this is fool proof

```
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

^/css/

> CondPattern is a perl compatible regular expression

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond

> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/css/